Able to run the code in python software but not in replit
I',m new here in python.im experiencing a problem .i'm able to run a particular program in python software but not in replit or any other compilers.
my code
import speech_recognition as sr  

# Capture audio input from the microphone                                                                             
r = sr.Recognizer()`                                                                                   
    with sr.Microphone() as source:                                                                       
       print("Kindly voice out your command!")                                                                                   
       audio = r.listen(source)   

    try:
        print("Interpreted as: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Apologies, the audio wasn't clear enough.")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("There was an issue retrieving results. Error: {0}".format(e))``

while executing this program my python software is asking for voice input but not replit.it is showing the error

modulenotfound error:no module named pyaudio;

but i have installed pyaudio
what should i do?
i tried doing it in python software and replit separately but getting the result in python software and not in replit. it is showing there is no module named pyaudio
